# Почему получается ошибка в функции?

Tags: d3.js

На примере с видео делаю простую фигуру

```js
paths();

function paths() {
  var canvas = d3.select(".paths").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

  var data = [{
      x: 10,
      y: 20
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    },
    {
      x: 10,
      y: 200
    }
  ];

  var group = canvas.append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y
    });

  group.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 5);
}
```

```html
<div class="paths"></div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Смотрел и делал по этому мануалу: https://youtu.be/0QlOBKBWcZ8?t=303

Но выдаёт ошибку вот такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каком месте я накосячил ?

Comment: ту же ошибку показывает сниппет so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В новом стандарте нет метода "d3.svg.line()", замените его на "d3.line()"

Comment: спасибо ...посмотрел дату выхода ролика ...старенькое видео

Comment: @MaximLensky это синтаксис 3 версии, насиная с 4, как в ответе

Comment: да я понял ...спасибо